# Importing gradient filled shapes from adobe illustrator to after effects

Tags: after-effects, animation

I am importing an illustrator file including svg shapes to after effects. The shapes in the files are filled with gradients and when I import them to AE they are all gray. Is there a way to quickly apply the gradient to all of the shapes? I am doing a lottie animation, so the fill needs to be gradient (not using an effect).

Some shapes also have a full layer size gray frame that I did not add in illustrator. So the layer basically has the shape I want (Group 1) and the full layer size shape (Group 2) covering everything else. IF I remove Group 2, I cannot add the fill to Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

The [Overlord plugin](https://www.battleaxe.co/overlord/) lets you move projects between Illustrator and After Effects in a better way than the built in processes do.  They have some support for gradients:

https://help.battleaxe.co/overlord/gradients.html

> #LIMITATIONS
> Because of the complexity of the workaround, there is a limit of 8 colors on gradients. Additional color stops will be
> ignored. Gradient strokes are supported, but the additional methods of
> applying gradients (Along stroke and Across stroke) are not possible
> in Ae and will be ignored. Radial gradient aspect ratio will be
> ignored

It's a good plugin, highly recommended